Unable to Change DNS Settings on ISP's Titanium 2122A ONT Router
I’m currently using an Titanium 2122A router (ONT) provided by ISP, and I’m facing some challenges with accessing specific settings. I cannot find the options for bridge mode or DNS settings; they are grayed out in the router's admin panel.
I've tried accessing the router using RouterSploit, but there was no Telnet or SSH access available. Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:
Attempted to access the router's web interface to change DNS settings but found them inaccessible. Contacted my ISP for support, but they were unable to provide a solution. Checked for any firmware updates but couldn’t find any available and no page to update firmware in wifi admin portal.
I am aware that I can change DNS settings on individual devices, but I would prefer to set this at the router level. I am looking for alternative methods to change the DNS settings on my router. Here are my questions:
Are there any specific commands or tools I can use to access hidden settings on this router? Is there a way to enable bridge mode or change DNS without Telnet or SSH access?
